# I have a question about salah ? Urgently

Tags: halal-haram, salat, dua

After saying the tashahudd I say the dua Allahumma inni zalamtu nafsi (this is some part of the dua) and blow on my chest is this this valid or bidah? And if you provide a hadith even better
Urgent

Answer (score -1):

After the final tashahhud; we should seek refuge against the punishment of hell, the punishment of the grave, from the trials of life and death, and from the turmoil of the Dajjal, from sin and heavy debt. Then there are some other dua'as too that can be recited, including the one you mention. However it does **not** say anything about blowing on the chest so this is likely an innovation (or bid'ah).

It was reported that Abu Hurayrah said: the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “When any one of you recites the Tashahhud [according to one report: when any one of you finishes the final Tashuhhud], let him seek refuge with Allaah from four things, let him say: ‘Allaahumma inni ‘aoodhu bika min ‘adhaab Jahannam wa min ‘adhaab al-qabri wa min fitnat il-mahyaa wa’l-mamaat wa min sharri fitnat il-maseekh id-dajjaal (O Allaah, I seek refuge with You from the punishment of Hell and the punishment of the grave, and from the trials of life and death and from the worst of the turmoil of the Dajjaal (antichrist)).’” Saheeh Muslim, 588.

It was also narrated that in addition to seeking refuge from these four, one should also seek refuge from sin and heavy debt. Al-Bukhaari and Muslim narrated from ‘Aa’ishah the wife of the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) that the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) used to say during his prayer: “Allaahumma inni a’oodhu bika min ‘adhaab al-qabri wa a’oodhi bika min fitnat il-maseekh id-dajjaal wa a’oodhi bika min fitnat il-mahyaa wa fitnat il-mamaat. Allaahumma inni a’oodhi bika min al-ma’tham wa’l-maghram (O Allaah, I seek refuge with You from the punishment of the grave and I seek refuge with You from the turmoil of the Dajjaal and I seek refuge with You from the trials of life and the trials of death. O Allaah, I seek refuge with You from sin and heavy debt).’” Someone said to him: “How often you seek refuge from heavy debt!” He said: “When a man gets into debt, he speak and tells lies, and he makes a promise and breaks it.” (al-Bukhaari, 833)

It was also narrated that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) taught Abu Bakr al-Siddeeq a du’aa which he could recite during his Salaah, as was narrated by al-Bukhaari. Abu Bakr al-Siddeeq (may Allaah be pleased with him) said to the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him), “Teach me a du’aa’ that I can recite during my salaah.” He said: “Say: ‘Allaahumma inni zalamtu nafsi zulman katheeran wa laa yaghfir ul-dhunoob illa anta, faghfir li maghfiratan min ‘indaka warhamni, innaka anta al-Ghafoor al-Raheem (O Allaah, indeed I have wronged myself greatly, and there is none who forgives sins besides You. So grant me forgiveness from You and have mercy on me, for You are the All-Forgiving, Most Merciful).’” (790). This du’aa may be recited in the final Tashahhud, after the prayers seeking refuge referred to above.

It was also narrated that after reciting the prayers seeking refuge, a person may recite any good du’aa he wishes, and may ask Allaah for anything he wishes of the good things of this world and the next. Abu Hurayrah (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “When any one of you recites the Tashahhud, let him seek refuge with Allaah from four things – from the punishment of Hell, the punishment of the grave, the trials of life and death, and the evils of the Dajjaal, then let him pray for himself for whatever he wants.” (Narrated by al-Nasaa’i, 1293).

And Allah knows best.